# What's the balance of (pro-)Russian forces in Ukraine between regular Russian units and Wagner, LPR+DPR armies etc.?

Tags: russian-federation, armed-conflict, ukraine, military

Are there some official Russian figures and/or Western estimates on what in the balance of (pro-)Russian forces engaged in Ukraine? Basically, how many are regular Russian forces vs various other kinds of volunteers and LPR+DPR armies?

Comment: My general impression was that there is no official Russian information on practically any aspect of what is happening in Ukraine.

Comment: This will be hard to know.  For one thing, while we, roughly, know the composition of the starting force, we don't really know the level of casualties and desertions those troops have seen, which units took the most losses, nor the level of replacement.  All of this will be, for understandable reasons, be kept Top Secret by Russia.  I am sure NATO/Ukraine intelligence has a ballpark guess, but anything they tell us will also quite possibly be not entirely candid.

Comment: @quarague There is defenetly official Russian information, but gues the problem you have with it is its credibility.